# Importing Android Project

Tags: android, import, project

We have a SVN set up across many developers. i am trying to import the project into Eclipse and i am getting the following error

http://variable3.com/files/screenshots/2011-02-22_1255.png

[image: error]

Comment: Is the project already in your workspace? maybe you deleted it from Eclipse but it is still there on the disk!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to change your workspace and then import the file into eclipse? You can do this by going to File > Switch Workspace.

Here's a good way to directly link SVN and eclipse 
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-ecl-subversion/
Essentially, it shows you how to install subclipse and checkout projects directly into your workspace. It might help you avoid these issues in the future.

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution:

-right click on Project Explorer

-Import...

-General->Existings project into workspace

-Browse your project

-Set checkbox "Copy projects into workspace"

-Finish

Comment: these are the options i get http://variable3.com/files/screenshots/2011-02-22_1430.png